# Two Shell_Exec Command with PHP button but still in the One powershell?

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have Powershell syntax that can get data using ReadExisting(), but the problem is... that syntax must compele php condition before (and some shell_exec syntax when page load)

I trying Get COM1 Data using powershell, and its working with this code

[cmd powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUu8o.png)

in that image, the first ReadExisting() can't declare the output because the device in COM1 not showing new result, when the devices show the result, trying the ReadExisting() again and i get what i want.

So (what in my opinion) the logic i should implement on PHP is : 
- Execute $port and $port.Open() first
- Execute ReadExisting() after that.

I'm trying making the php code like this

```
<?php
    $result = shell_exec('powershell $port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM1,9600,None,8,one ; Get-Variable ;  $port.Open(); $port.ReadExisting() ');

    echo $result 

?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="RUN" /><br/>
</form>

<?php
    function testfun()
    {
      $result2 = shell_exec('powershell $port.ReadExisting()');
      echo $result2;
    }

    if(array_key_exists('test',$_POST)){
       testfun();
    }
?>
```

but the button not showing the result like that in the powershell. What i can see problably because i'm making two shell_exec?, and yes the $result is working (i'm already testing it and i can see the port connection variable)

it's there possible method making continues shell command with button condition? thank you!.

Answer (score 0):

I think the sessions of `Powershell` can be of help. This kind of problems are usually solved with that. The detailed documentation of starting and maintaining of sessions are available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pssessions?view=powershell-6)

If you use a session, the commands can have continuity.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Trying using session but unfortunately i can't because this code will become localhost and some of computer has error when doing the session. Thx for the reply, that documentation really helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

Use this: (`2>&1` in `shell_exec`)

```
$result2 = shell_exec('powershell $port.ReadExisting() 2>&1');
echo $result2;
```

`>&` is the syntax to redirect a stream to another file descriptor - 0 is stdin, 1 is stdout, and 2 is stderr.

`2` refers to the second file descriptor of the process, i.e. stderr.

`>` means redirection.

`&1` means the target of the redirection should be the same location as the first file descriptor, i.e. stdout.

Comment: thx you for the reply, sir! trying your solution it seems working, but now i has error from echoing the result2. 

"You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At line:1 char:1 + $port.ReadExisting() ; + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull"

Comment: Trying to using GetVariable on result2 and it seems the variable is missing so thats why i can't call the $port